# How to rename a file based on the beginning file name?

Tags: batch-file, rename

I need a routine to rename files to the converted file names and delete the original in a given directory.
It has to look for just the beginning string `GL_AVG`, `GL_DEFAULT`, `GL_END` because after that the file name will be changing daily so can't be hardcoded, *(that I can do)*.

Original Files:

```
GL_AVG_2017-02-15_08-54-56.txt
GL_DEFAULT_2017-02-15_08-54-34.txt
GL_END_2017-02-15_08-55-12.txt
```

Converted To:

```
GL_AVG_Feb_2017.txt
GL_DEFAULT_Feb_2017.txt
GL_END_Feb_2017.txt
```

So far, I have the following code to parse the year and filemonth, but having trouble trying to rename using these variables.

```
For /F "eol=_ tokens=3 delims=_" %%a in ('dir /b *.txt') do set yy=%%~na  
For /F "eol=_ tokens=2 delims=-" %%a in ('dir /b *.txt') do set filemonth=%%~na

if %filemonth% == "01" set mm=Dec
if %filemonth% == "02" set mm=Jan
if %filemonth% == "03" set mm=Feb
if %filemonth% == "04" set mm=Mar
if %filemonth% == "05" set mm=Apr
if %filemonth% == "06" set mm=May
if %filemonth% == "07" set mm=Jun
if %filemonth% == "08" set mm=Jul
if %filemonth% == "09" set mm=Aug
if %filemonth% == "10" set mm=Sep
if %filemonth% == "11" set mm=Oct
if %filemonth% == "12" set mm=Nov

set dd=%%c

)
```

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: Your IF statements will never be true.  It is a string comparison.  You have quotes on one side of the comparison but not the other.

Comment: Thanks for the the catch.  Any ideas on the renaming piece?

Comment: Do you intentionally subtract a month?

Comment: On what basis is 01 December? 02 is January, and 12 is November???

Answer (score 2):

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
:: build a pseudo array with the month names
Set M#=101
For %%A in (Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
) do Set Month[!M#:~-2!]=%%A&Set /A M#+=1
:: Rename
For /f "tokens=1-4* delims=_-" %%A in (
  'Dir /B GL_*_20*_*.txt'
) Do Echo Ren "%%A_%%B_%%C-%%D-%%E" "%%A_%%B_!Month[%%D]!_%%C.txt"
```

Sample output

```
Ren "GL_AVG_2017-02-15_08-54-56.txt" "GL_AVG_Feb_2017.txt"
Ren "GL_DEFAULT_2017-02-15_08-54-34.txt" "GL_DEFAULT_Feb_2017.txt"
Ren "GL_END_2017-02-15_08-55-12.txt" "GL_END_Feb_2017.txt"
```

If the output looks ok remove the echo in the last line.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the string-replacement function, which looks like:

```
%VariableName:[OldText]=[NewText]%
```

Or in your case:

```
for /F "eol=_ tokens=2 delims=-" %%a in ('dir /b *.txt') do (
    call :RenameFile %%~na )
exit /B

:RenameFile [%1: Name of file to be renamed]
    set Filename=%1

    ::Look for "2017-01", change it to "2017_Jan"
    ::Repeat for each possible month.
    set Filename=%Filename:2017-01=2017_Jan%
    set Filename=%Filename:2017-02=2017_Feb%
    set Filename=%Filename:2017-03=2017_Mar%
    set Filename=%Filename:2017-04=2017_Apr%
    set Filename=%Filename:2017-05=2017_May%
    set Filename=%Filename:2017-06=2017_Jun%
    set Filename=%Filename:2017-07=2017_Jul%
    set Filename=%Filename:2017-08=2017_Aug%
    set Filename=%Filename:2017-09=2017_Sep%
    set Filename=%Filename:2017-10=2017_Oct%
    set Filename=%Filename:2017-11=2017_Nov%
    set Filename=%Filename:2017-12=2017_Dec%
    rename %1 %Filename%
exit /B
```

Alternately, you may want to look at http://www.dostips.com/?t=Snippets.MapLookup